# "Null"s are being added randomly to a list

Tags: list-manipulation, computational-geometry

I am having troubles trying to run the following code. It is meant to calculate a series of rays reflections inside a closed room (2D).
`Collision[]` is a function that returns the intersection point (ray hit) with the closest object/wall. 
`p = {10,0}` is the source location.
`line` is a list contains `{a,b}` where `y=ax+b` is the ray's line equation.

**Code:**

```
path[line_, k_] :=  ( 
  p = {10, 0};
   l = {p};
  line1 = line;
  For[i = 1, i <= k, i = i + 1, 
    p = collision[line1, p];
    AppendTo[l, p];
    If[9.5 <= p[[1]] <= 10.5 && p[[2]] == 15 , Break[], 
     line1 = {-1/line1[[1]], p[[2]] - -1/line1[[1]]*p[[1]]}]
     ]
   l
  )
```

Calling this function with the needed parameters:
`path[{1, -10}, 2]`
Returns the output:
`{{10 Null, 0}, {20 Null, 10 Null}, {0, 30 Null}}`
While the expected output is supposed to be:
`{{10, 0}, {20, 10}, {0, 30}}`
Where did I go wrong? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: In `p[[2]] - -1/line1[[1]]` probably you mean a single `-` ?

Comment: No, I wrote it this way just for the sake of (my own) convenience (look more clear to me in the Traditional form)

Comment: Your `For` loop returns `Null` that you then multiply with the list `l`. Did you mean  `; l` after the `For`?

Comment: Thank you ! The problem is solved ! :)

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rhermans has it right: You forgot a semicolon. What's happening is that the `For[...]` evaluates to `Null`. Since you left the `;` out before the last `l`, the result you're getting is the product of `Null` and `l`.